# What does やっちまえ mean?

Tags: slang

As the title says: What does やっちまえ mean?

Comment: Can you provide a little context where you saw it used, if possible?

Comment: You've only given a single word to give you translation of and, unfortunately, Japanese is quirky to the point that can't be done. Be more specific next time or the answer to your question will be either partial or not exactly correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

「やっちまえ」 is the tough guy's colloquial way of saying 「やってしまえ」 and it can mean so many different things because the verb 「やる」 has quite a few meanings.

It can mean "Beat him up!", "Get him/her/them!", "Kill'em!", etc.  It could even mean something I am not allowed to say on here.

Another possibility is when やる means "to give something to someone".  In that case, 「やっちまえ」 means "Give it to (someone)!  (Someone) needs it more than you do!", which is much more peaceful than the first set of possible meanings above.

So, the best thing to do is to provide some context if none of the above seem to fit.

Comment: something I am not allowed to say on here >>> どうぞ！

Comment: 上品なボクに何を言わせようとしているんだい？「みんなでやったれ、このあま！」とか、恥ずかしくて言えないよ。

Comment: 言うてるやんｗｗｗ-------